# Depends in FastAPI doesn't generate description about field on /docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I have some code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    field1: str = Field(..., title="this is title")
    field2: str = Field(..., description="this is description")


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/send_request")
def recv_requests(req: MyModel = Depends()):
    print(req)
    return {'status': 200}


uvicorn.run(app)
```

And /docs looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsZnL.png)

Field1 and field2 don't have **description** or **title**, which I wrote in MyModel, but I need it. How do I make descriptions to fields using Depends()?

Comment: refer https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4700, they have a workaround for this with `dataclass` and use `Query` instead of `Field`

Comment: @Naveen Yeah, thank you) I saw it too and found it as a strange decision, but there are no more options))